# Find dot and replace with coma on decimal numbers (Notepad++ RegEx)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to replace dot with comas on numbers: `;;;559.34;` to `;;;559,34;` for example.

I need to use regex, because there are lots of other numbers using dots (date, time and others), but the one I need to replace always starts with `;;;` and ends with `;` like non other.

I was able to find those numbers using `;;;\d+.[0-9]{2};` but I can't replace all dots using this.

Thank you.

Comment: try ;;;(\d+)(\.)(\d+);

Comment: I can't use find and replace with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In notepad++ you can use

```
;;;\d+\K\.(?=[0-9]{2};)
```

**Explanation**

- `;;;\d+` Match `;;;` and 1+ digits
- `\K\.` Forget what is matched so far
- `(?=[0-9]{2};)` Positive lookahead, assert 2 digits and `;` at the right

In the replacement use a comma.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AVxN5w/1)

[image]